# Integrate SharePoint with ASP.Net applications

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library

My scenario: in my company (more than 2.000 people), people were used to save files in many network shared folders, each with different set of users able to access it.

Now we are replacing the network folders with sharepoint, i.e. people are instructed to create SP document libraries, with the proper access rights, instead of using network folders as a shared storage.

Also, we have a lot of intranet web applications (ASP.NET), and it happens quite often that people have to upload files in these application.

Now the bad in using SP: users used to browse the shared folders and select the file to upload. Now with SP they need to download the file from SP user interface, save it somewhere and then upload it like they used to do. And that's bad.

Since SP can be accessed programmatically, it's reasonable to think to some "SharePoint document browser" component I can use within my applications to browse, select and use files (i.e. pick a file from SP and upload it to the application).

Obviously each user should be able to browse only the SP libraries he has access to.
Also, it would be nice if this component could browse also the personal OneDrive of each user

What is the best approach to this issue?
I read a lot (too much) of documentation about authentication and SPClient in NET, but cannot figure out the right combination to use. 
Our company is using both office365 and SP on premises (SPserver 2016): as a start, I'd like to access at least at the libraries created in office365 environment

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to leave the files in SharePoint and link to them from your applications rather then uploading copies of documents all over the place.

What you are proposing to do defeats the whole purpose of having SharePoint.

Comment: Well, I should have explained better my scenario. The intranet applications I want to integrate with SP are often a backend for public applications, where we need to expose some files. SP as a public front end is not an option here, even just as linked fies

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your Asp.net application as a provider hosted addin(either Asp.net forms or Asp.net MVC Application), which will communicate with Sharepoint to get file & it's details using Rest Api or CSOM.
 Benefits of this:- Single Sign On, Access Management can be done, IRM can be Applied, All your Asp.net Application will have integrated Architecture n many more... Hope this Helps

Comment: No, Provider hosted add-in can be hosted using Azure, IIS, or any third party hosted services...  The Application which is hosted by SPO(Sharepoint Online) is called as Sharepoint hosted add-in

Comment: Thanks @amardeep, but still not getting it, does it means I can just modify my current applications so they can interact with SP, or I have to move them somehow? in any case, what I'm missing is the flow that start from authentication and goes to the call to Rest API / CSOM.